# Fileinfo functions not working in Xampp 1.8.2

Tags: php, xampp

The fileinfo functions from php http://php.net/manual/en/ref.fileinfo.php are not working when I try to use the finfo_open and finfo_file functions in a php script where I will let users upload a file. Although php's site says that the functions will work if php's version is greater than or equal to 5.3.0 and I have xampp 1.8.2 which has php 5.4.16, it still produces a fatal error as --- Fatal error: Call to undefined function finfo_open() in ..... ---. I am using these functions in the procedural way not in object-oriented way and I am using eclipse helios as my php editor. Any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to php.ini (or simply from xampp window, near Apache -> Config -> php.ini)
Find line:

```
;extension=php_fileinfo.dll
```

and uncomment it

Comment: Well I did as you said but the fatal error is still occurring.---Fatal error: Call to undefined function finfo_open() in... --

Comment: It worked. I had to restart the server to load the module. Thanks.